# Date range from weeknumber + year

Tags: .net, date

I have 2 dropdowns 1 with weeknumbers 1 with years. 
I want to extract the date range from this data.

So:

Weeknumber 13 year 2009 would give:

monday  23 march 2009
tuesday 24 march 2009
...

VB.Net preferred but C# sollution is also ok.

Edit: 
Ok I guess I should have mentioned this is for European dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var date = DateTime.MinValue + 2009.Years() + 13.Weeks();
```

by using [Fluent DateTime](http://fluentdatetime.codeplex.com/) project on Codeplex.

Answer (score 5):

```
CultureInfo curCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;

DateTime targetDate = curCulture.Calendar.AddWeeks(new DateTime([year], 1, 1), [Week]);

DayOfWeek targetWeekDay =
    curCulture.Calendar.GetDayOfWeek(targetDate);

DateTime targetBeginningOfWeek = targetDate.AddDays(-1*Convert.ToInt16(targetWeekDay));
```

targetBeginningOfWeek will contain first day of that week, add 7 days and get rest of day in that week

Answer (score 3):

Try to use these following functions:

```
Public Function Week2Date1(ByVal Week2Date2 As Date) As Date
    Week2Date1 = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -4, Week2Date2)

End Function

Public Function Week2Date2(ByVal WeekNo As Integer) As Date
    Week2Date2 = DateSerial(Now.Year, 1, (WeekNo) * 7)

End Function
```

I am using these to determine the date of the Mondays and Fridays of every week number.

where:

- on Function Week2Date2 will return the Friday of the Week Number and
- on Function Week2Date1 will return the Monday of the Week Number from the date value returned by Week2Date2.

Answer (score 2):

Below code gets the date range from week number and year. But its written in Java.
       Hope it helps.

```
   System.out.println("date Range from weekNumber and year but in Java");
   System.out.println(); // print a blank line

   // get the input from the user
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.print("Enter the week : ");
   int weekNumber  = sc.nextInt(); 
   System.out.print("Enter the Year: ");
   int year = sc.nextInt() ;



   Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
   //cal.setTime(new Date());

   cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
   cal.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, weekNumber);

   SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");

   cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
   System.out.println(formatter.format(cal.getTime())); // start date

   cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 6);
   System.out.println(formatter.format(cal.getTime())); // end date
```